# JavaScript/HTML - Difference between JS result and text in the browser

Tags: javascript, email, web-scraping

I'm very new in JavaScript and I'm stucked for days on this problem:

There is a web page which contains email addresses. These addresses are written in JavaScript. The code in  is slightly changed after every page refresh, but on the web browser I can see a proper form of the e-mail (this is probably a protection against web scraping, but data is public and 100% legal). Here is an example of the code after the first and the second refresh:

1. `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">var i='&#109;a'+'i&#108;'+'&#116;o';var a='rora&#64;rorafeb&#46;fx';document.write('<a href="'+i+':'+a+'"  onclick="_kt.i(10854, 20);" class="eyJyb3QiOiJpdCJ9">'+a+'</a>');</script>`
2. `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">var i='&#109;a'+'i&#108;'+'&#116;o';var a='aben&#64;ebensro&#46;sk';document.write('<a href="'+i+':'+a+'"  onclick="_kt.i(10854, 20);" class="eyJlIjoiYSJ9">'+a+'</a>');</script>`

Theproper form of email should be: 'eben@ebensro.sk'

Could you give me an advice, how it is possible and how to get this email?

Thanks

Comment: So the two text results above refer to the same e-mails? Because if so, I feel like it'd be pretty hard to get the e-mail. It looks to me as if they might be transforming the text using their own internal tools (via hash or something), so it'd be pretty difficult to decrypt that.

Comment: @Zhouster Thank you for response. In my opinion, it could not be so hard =because every browser can do that. But I'm new so I dont know.

Comment: You're sure the second one isn't aben@ rather than eben@? And the first one surely not ebensro.sk at all, looks like it's rora@rorafeb.fx.

Comment: *"...how it is possible and how to get this email?"* Get it where? Where will your code be running? Within the page (which seems odd, but perhaps you're doing a bookmarklet)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to scrape the JavaScript in its entirety and execute it in something like jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/. All the emails will be written out in the results. Then you could just write another piece of JS to parse the email addresses out of the anchor tags written out.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a click on that anchor, and get the innerHTML email written by the function.

Answer (score 0):

The email addresses are in basically cleartext in the code, in the `a` variable. `aben&#64;ebensro&#46;sk` is just `aben@ebensro.sk` written using [decimal character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) (`&#64;` is a `@`, `&#46;` is a `.`). `rora&#64;rorafeb&#46;fx` is just `rora@rorafeb.fx`.

Comment: I understand what you're talking about. But the problem is that those are not proper emails. Both of these texts are actually eben@ebensro.sk

Comment: http://www.azet.sk/firma/10854/eben-spol-s-r-o/ Have a look en the source code of this page and as you will see, email will be changed after each refresh.

Comment: @user3371056: If that's the case, you'll need to find out what the logic of the `_kt.i` function is, as it apparently modifies the link when you click it.